# Python Service / Daemon

Tags: python, linux, service, python-2.7, daemon

I'm writing a Python script that I need to have start at boot (it should continue running forever once it is started). I would like to be able to manage the service via running a command like:

```
sudo service my-service (and either start, stop, restart, etc.)
```

I have been reading a lot into it and would really like to finish my project. I saw this but would need help implementing it if it were to work [Linux Start-up Script](http://peterlairdtech.blogspot.com/2010/05/example-linux-startup-service-for.html). I'm not even sure where to start, I don't really know how to program in bash but I'm open to all solutions. Thank you ahead of time, and I appreciate all responses!

Comment: What Linux distro are you using?

Comment: I'm running a version of Debian on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Take a look at some of the scripts in the `/etc/init.d/` directory.

Comment: I found this one that may be helpful [pastebin code link](http://pastebin.com/qxiVjs7M). Could I reuse a lot of what it has? If I can any advice, especially because I need to integrate it with a Python script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [zdaemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zdaemon). It provides a simple way to daemonize a Python process.

Then you can write an init.d script for it - based on your OS.
Or you can use a tool like Upstart, supervisord to control the daemon.

My init.d script (on centos 5.8) looks like this:

```
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

. /etc/sysconfig/network

APP_PATH=/path/to/your/app
PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
USER=user

start() {
    cd $APP_PATH
    zdaemon -C app.zdconf start
}

stop() {
    cd $APP_PATH
    zdaemon -C app.zdconf stop
}

check_status() {
        cd $APP_PATH
        zdaemon -C app.zdconf status
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        check_status
        ;;
  restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)

esac
exit 0
```

Where app.zdconf is the zdaemon configuration file.